# Is PhpStorm not supporting Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I've read Laravel 5.1 documentation:
http://www.golaravel.com/laravel/docs/5.1/eloquent/#retrieving-single-models

On it, there's the following sample code:

```
$model = App\Flight::findOrFail(1);
```

But when I try to use this in PhpStorm, the autocompletion dropdown does not show such method:

[image]

I'm using PhpStrom vesion 9.0.2.

Comment: Have you tried installing the Laravel Plugin and Laravel IDE Helper for PHPStorm?

Comment: sorry,i try now , because i just use phpstrom